# Gradient in HTML Canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

My first question in StackOverflow.
Is there a way to create only LinearGradient in HTML5 Canvas,but use it on all different rectangular shapes and size and get the same fill pattern.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 20, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0,"black");
grd.addColorStop(1,"red");
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
```

Use this gradient to to fill two rectangles of different shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use one single gradient to draw many rectangles, you have to use a normalized gradient (== coordinates in [0,1]), then draw your rect in a normalized way.

Expl :

```
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 1.0, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0,"black");
grd.addColorStop(1,"red");
```

Then draw your rectangle with :

```
function drawNormalizedRect(context, x,y,w,h) {
   context.save();
   context.translate(x,y);
   context.scale(w,h);
   context.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
   context.restore();
}
```

Expl of use

```
ctx.fillStyle = grd; 
drawNormalizedRect(ctx, 200, 320, 40, 50);
```

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById('cv');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 1.0, 0);
    grd.addColorStop(0,"black");
    grd.addColorStop(1,"red");
    ctx.fillStyle = grd; 


    for (var i=0; i<20; i++) {
       drawNormalizedRect(ctx,Math.random()*600, Math.random()*400, 10+Math.random()*60, 10+Math.random()*60);
    }


    function drawNormalizedRect(ctx,x,y,w,h) {
       ctx.save();
       ctx.translate(x,y);
       ctx.scale(w,h);
       ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
       ctx.restore();
    }
```

```html
<canvas width=600 height=400 id='cv' ></canvas>
```